# Android Profiler Thread and Process Look up by Id

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, android-profiler

I'm trying to debug my app with one of the profiler tools of Android Studio.

I'm trying to find exactly where the main thread of my CameraActivity is located within the trace file.

I'm using the perfetto UI in order to open the trace as a webpage. ***Please look at the attached picture***. [image]

I see that I can narrow down to my package. However I'm trying to find the actual main thread. specifically the Handler that its possible causing memory leaks.

In order to get the process Id and Thread Id, I placed this Log.d call inside the handleMessage method of the Handler.

```
Log.d("iinnside_","see: " + yes.getLooper().getThread().getId() + " string: "+
                    yes.getLooper().getThread().toString());
```

this Log.d call gave me the results:

20815-20815 D/iinnside_: see: 2 string: Thread[main,5,main]

From what I understand based on the configuartion of my Log outputs the digits: **20815-20815**
represent the process and Id I need. However I can't find them via the perfetto UI display. Besides,
according to the Log.d call above the main thread has an id = 2.

**In software engineering there must be a common number assigned** to the main thread of an application. ***What is the most common number used?***

How can I make sense of these processes Id's on the Threads of my app?

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (and of course Android), the main thread ID is the same as the process id (PID). In your example, 20815 is both the app's pid and main thread ID.

I don't know how your `yes` object is instantiated, but it looks like a `Handler`, which is associated with a `Looper` and runs on that `Looper`'s thread, different from the main thread. It so happens that the thread has id = 2.

By the way, your screenshot shows the old UI of system trace. If you open it in the new Perfetto [trace viewer](https://ui.perfetto.dev/#!/) or import it into [Android Studio profilers](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler#import-traces), you should be able to see the thread IDs more clearly.